# Can I use a promise that receives and array of five promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to have a function that receives five promises?

```
function getDadosQuestionarios(getDadosQuestionarioET, getDadosQuestionarioST, getDadosQuestionarioWAI, getDadosQuestionarioOQ10, getDadosQuestionarioAQP9){
    return Promise.all([getDadosQuestionarioET, getDadosQuestionarioST, getDadosQuestionarioWAI, getDadosQuestionarioOQ10, getDadosQuestionarioAQP9])
  .then(function(values){
    return [values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]]
  })
}
```

I've tested with two and it worked, but when I add a third promise, I get an error: `getDadosQuestionarioWAI is not defined`.

Comment: It should work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: A promise can return anything, even an array of 5 promises

Comment: What's the sense behind putting the values of the array in a new array instead of just returning `values`?

Comment: none. I just copied from another example, but I've changed that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure it is possible, take a look at the following code as an example, but also note about how it is possible to catch errors when an argument is supplied as undefined.

```
(async function(){
    const delay = time => new Promise(res=>setTimeout(()=>res(time),time));
    console.log('Start', new Date())

    const testFn = function(a,b,c,d,e){
        // Note: Arguments is a built in property.
        if(Array.from(arguments).indexOf(undefined)!=-1){
            return new Promise((res,rej)=>rej('Undefined Argument'));
        }else{
            return Promise.all([a,b,c,d,e]);
        }
    };
    testFn(delay(1),delay(2),delay(3),delay(4),undefined).then(data=>{
        console.log('Done', new Date());
    }).catch(err=>console.log('ERROR:',err));
})();
```